# Adding tags of HTML table

Tags: c

I want to make 5tab6tab7 like `<tr><td>4<td><td>5<td><td>7<td></tr>` but 4 5 7 will look like `<tr><td>457<td></tr>`...How I can do it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
char str[1000];


while(scanf("%s",str)) {
    printf("<tr>");
    printf("<td>%s<td>", str);
    printf("</tr>");
}
```

Comment: Html tags on Console using `C`? This question is not clear, please elaborate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add html tags in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19626513/add-html-tags-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

do it like

```
printf("<td>%s &nbsp;</td>", str);
```

Comment: I got this after changing it `<tr><td>7 &nbsp;<td></tr><tr><td>6 &nbsp;<td></tr><tr><td>9 &nbsp;<td></tr>`